# How to Save user then save upload image

Tags: node.js, multer

i want to save user(check is all information is correct) then upload image
any help please ?

```
app.post('/users', upload, (req, res) => {
      if (req.fileError) {
        return res.send(req.fileError)
      }
      let body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
      if(req.file)
        body.avatar = req.file.filename;

      const user = new User(body);

      user.save().then((user) => {
        return user.generateAuthToken();
      }).then((token) => {
        res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
      }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
      })
    })``
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit please? What do you want to achieve? Save your `User` object in a file on the disk?